# Local git repository - are SSH keys needed?

Tags: git, ssh, git-svn

I am using Windows 7, and interested in using git-svn locally, with a remote svn server.

I've installed Git, and found [this tutorial](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html) on working with Git on Windows.

Is the part about SSH keys in the tutorial relevant for me, given that I do not intend to access a remote Git repository?

Comment: No, it is not relevant for you in this particular case. Just remember it when you start working with actual Git repositories.

Comment: Would have accepted this if it was an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you're locally using Git but your server is SVN, which means you'd be using git-svn. Svn servers typically use basic http auth (username/password). You can find commands [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) for passing credentials to server in your setup phase.

To answer the question explicitly, Git clients support multiple Authentication mechanism and the one you ought to use depend entirely upon what auth your Git/SVN server expects. You should contact administrator of your repository and find out what auth methods are supported by the server